# Mongoose - Retreive ObjectId with attribute and pass it to an insert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

With mongoose 4.9.4, I have two models, a User model and a Customer model.

A customer is always attached to a user (user 1 - n customer).

Now to create a Customer in the front, I use a dropdown in a form to select a unique attribute from a user (which is called "trigramUser"), retreive the user objectId with this attribute and pass it to an attribute for the new cutomer.

the createCustomer method :

1. Find a user objectId with the attribute "trigramUser"
2. Convert this objectId to string (id.str)
3. Replace the req.body.userCustomer attribute to create a new customer with the  objectId as a string

**customerController.js**

```
exports.createCustomer = (req, res) => {
    console.log('Creation of the customer '+req.body.siretCustomer+' in progress.');
    console.log('Worker attached to the customer '+req.body.userCustomer+' .');
    database.getConnection();
    user.findOne( { trigramUser: req.body.userCustomer } , '_id', (err, id) => {
        var newCustomer = {
            sireCustomer          : req.body.siretCustomer,
            // attributes...
            userCustomer          : id.str
    };
    console.log('ID worker : '+id.str+' .');
    customer.create(newCustomer, (err) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).json(err.stack);
        res.status(200).json(
            { message: 'Customer '+req.body.siretCustomer+'
             has been successfully created.' }
        );
        });
    });
};
```

**customer.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'), Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var customerSchema = new Schema({
  siretCustomer:
    { type: String, required: true, minlength: 15, maxlength: 15 },
  // attributes ...
  userCustomer:
    [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
}, { collection: 'customer' });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Customer', customerSchema, 'customer');
```

**user.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'), Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    trigramUser:
        { type: String, required: true },
    // attributes...
    customersUser:
        [{ type: String, ref: 'Customer'}]
}, { collection: 'user'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema, 'user');
```

However, for the createCustomer method, the console shows when I submit the form :

```
Creation of the customer 987987987987987 in progress.
Worker attached to the customer PLD .
ID worker : undefined .
```

So the req.body.userCustomer reach the `user.find({}, '_id',` method.
Now if I write in Mongo :

```
db.user.findOne({trigramUser:'PDL'})._id.str;
```

The output is `5988897d7b55ba0548d95da6`.

Why when I print req.body.userCustomer (which is the string 'PDL') in the method `user.findOne({trigramUser: req.body.userCustomer}, '_id',` the string is null and the query doesn't work?

Comment: Huh??? Not sure what you think you are doing here but presuming you import from the user model to `user` then that would be `user.findOne({ trigramUser: req.body.userCustomer }).then( currUser => console.log(currUser._id) )`. And don't worry about being a "string" or an `ObjectId` because wherever you pass it to the correct value will in fact be used.

Comment: Yes because a customer needs a user objectId to be created, so I fetch the user objectId with a unique attribute "trigramUser" with the method findOne.
About your comment it didn't solve the problem but thank you anyway, it did step it further since I don't have the line `ID worker : undefined.` anymore in console. I guess it is because the promise is never launched.

Comment: You miunderstand. Your `(err,id)` does not have `id` with **only** the value. It's **still the whole document**, but only stripped down to one property i.e `{ _id: 5988897d7b55ba0548d95da6 }`. So you would be accessing instead as `id._id`, or more realistically by the more accurate naming reflecting what actually happens just like I'm showing you. I don't guess anything here. I actually "know" or do not bother saying anything.